# Magento 2.1.5 eav_entity_attribute doesn't get updated

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Shouldn't the eav_entity_attribute table be updated when you run magento indexer:reindex or is it generated by something else? 
The reason I ask is that the table was corrupted during data migration and it is causing multiple issues on the site.

I tried to empty the table (after taking a backup) and then run reindex. Nothing appeared in the table. 
There doesn't seem to be anything relevant in any of the logs.

Answer (score 0):

EAV tables are not updated when reindex is run. The "eav_entity_attribute" table stores the group and attribute set of all attributes.
What data or what attributes are corrupted?

Comment: During migration quite a bit of data has been corrupted. We have manually fixed product attribute sets where fields displayed in create/edit product didn't match the attribute set as it was shown in stores->attribute sets. At the moment the problem is Categories. When we create or edit a category all the fields are correctly shown, but they are not saved. It looks to me like the form is getting the data from a different table than the save function. Also it looks like eav_entity_attribute table could in theory be created from processing other tables